# In a react class: How do I pass a variable inside same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning ReactJS and need to pass a variable inside the same component.

Here's an example

```
var DataBase = [
    {
        position: 1
    },
    {
        position: 2
    },
    {
        position: 3
    },
    {
        position: 4
    }
];

var Component = React.createClass({

    getDefaultProps: function() {
        var counter = 0;
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        var dbPos = this.props.db[counter+1].position;
        return dbPos;
    }, 

    render: function () {
         return (
            <div className="Component">
                {this.dbPos}
            </div>
         ); 
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Component db={DataBase} />,
    document.getElementById('main')
);
```

So, this obviously doesn't work. What I need is to pass `var dbPos` created in `componentDidMount` to the `render` (without any events like onClick). This will be time driven, like 10 seconds in each position with setTimeout().

Is this possible? How? Is there a better solution? I'll appreciate all your help.

Comment: You can attach variables to `this`, or have a method like `getDbPosition`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That problem may regard *state handling*. There are multiple ways to handle the application's state in a React application, but I will assume that you are interested in keeping `dbPos` as part of the component's state (and that you may be mutating it in the future). To achieve this, simply use `this.setState` and `this.state`.

Before I show the example, I will state a few other mistakes in your code snippet:

- `getDefaultProps` should return a hash object of the props, not declare them with var (that would make them scoped to the method rather than the component instance)
- `counter`, as a prop, must be referred as `this.props.counter`. Note that `counter` is not part of this component's state, and can only change with a respective change of that prop in an upper level of the component tree.

With that in mind:

```
var Component = React.createClass({

    getDefaultProps: function() {
        return {counter: 0};
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        var dbPos = this.props.db[this.props.counter+1].position;
        this.setState({ // change the state of this component
          dbPos: dbPos
        })
    },

    render: function () {
         return (
            <div className="Component">
                {this.state.dbPos}
            </div>
         ); 
    }
});
```

---

If you do not want `dbPos` to mutate as part of the component's state, simply make a new method for retrieving the intended `position`. No mutable state will be involved here.

```
var Component = React.createClass({

  getDefaultProps() {
    return {counter: 0};
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    // no longer needed
  },    
  getPosition() {
    return this.props.db[this.props.counter + 1].position;
  },

  render () {
    return (
        <div className="Component">
            {this.getPosition()}
        </div>
      ); 
  }
});
```

Comment: That didn't work. Console return (this.state is null)
EDIT: yeah, with that 2nd method it works! :) Thanks!