# React Class how to pass variables in all methods in same file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a problem understanding the concept. I want to pass windColor variable from inside of renderWeather() to render() and function alertKitesurf

I should use this.state and setState or I can do it with variables?

my code doesn't work.

PS. why outside the class you need to add function method() while inside the class's brackets you don't need?

```
import React, ....

class WeatherList extends Component {   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fixit = 'blue';   }   //  render single city   
renderWeather(cityData) {
        const lol = this;
        const name = cityData.city.name;
        const temp = cityData.list.map(weather => (weather.main.temp - 272));
        const humi = cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.humidity);
        const wind = cityData.list.map(weather => weather.wind.speed);
        //  Kitesurf alert!
        console.log(lol.fixit);
        const windColor = alertKitesurf(wind);
        lol.fixit = windColor;
        return (
          <tr key={name}>
            <td className="col-md-3">{name}</td>
            <Chart data={temp} color="blue" />
            <Chart data={humi} color="blue" />
            <Chart data={wind} color={windColor} />
          </tr>
        );   }


  render() {
    let fixdiv;
    if (this.fixit === 'blue') {
      fixdiv = <div>test</div>;
    }
    else {
      fixdiv = <div>OMG</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <table className="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th className="col-md-3">City</th>
              <th className="col-md-3">Temperature</th>
              <th className="col-md-3">Humidity</th>
              <th className="col-md-3">Wind Speed</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.props.weather.map(this.renderWeather)}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        {fixdiv}
      </div>
    );   } } //  function(state) -> function( {weather}) -> weather : weather -> weather function mapStateToProps({ weather }) {   return { weather }; }

function alertKitesurf(wind) {   let color = 'blue';   for (let windspeed of wind) {
    if (windspeed > 7) {
       color = 'red';
    }   }   if (color === 'red') {
    alert("WIND SPOTTED! (14+knots) LETS GO KITSURF!");   }   return color; }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WeatherList);
```

Comment: can you format the code?

Comment: You can use `this` keyword before a variable to make it global to a particular class. If your variable is changing the render function then you should put this in state and change the value using setState method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use state.

Lets explorer this for a while.

In your constructor you pass

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    windColor: 'blue'
  }
}
```

Then inside any method of that class (including render method) you refer to it as `this.state.windColor`.

Even if you'll pass it as a param, you'll need to pass it as `somefunc(this.state.windColor)`.

For more information see this: [In a react class: How do I pass a variable inside same component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266406/in-a-react-class-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-inside-same-component#36266663)

And regarding to your last question.

If you mean

> Why writing the function keyword outside the class & without the function keyword inside class.

Well that's more of a javascript syntax conversion. I think you can write the function keyword though.

Consider this new way of using arrow functions with binding of the `this` keyword.

```js
class Awesomeness extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  
  some = () => {
    console.log('something wild while this is bound to the class\'s this!')
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div> You are awesome! </div>
  }
}
```

More on this read this awesome article: [React Binding Patterns: 5 Approaches for Handling `this`](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56)

Or you can easily understand it as this.

```js
//This

const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b() {
    console.log(this.a)
  }
}

//Equals this

const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: function() {
    console.log(this.a)
  }
}
```